# Expo manifest.android.config missing in build apk

Tags: android, react-native, expo, vue-native

**TypeError**
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.default.manifest.android.config.googleMaps')

https://sentry.io/ error show me that key config are missing in my manifest in apk.

Any ideas how to fix it?

**APK**

[image]

**DEV**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8781

I solved this by replacing **Constants.manifest.android.config.googleMaps.apiKey** call with my own small config json (or just string) in all project. On standalone apk **Constants.manifest.android.config.googleMaps.apiKey** - is not exists.
react-native-map works fine